# How to always check the time on Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I make a alternate entry point that display a dialog " Hello new week " on the first day of each week.

My code :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        if ( args != null && args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("autorun") ){

             MyApp theApp = new MyApp();
             theApp.pushThread.start();
             theApp.enterEventDispatcher(); 
       } 
        else {       
            MyApp theApp = new MyApp();
            theApp.pushScreen(new MyScreen());
            theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
       }        
    }


    Thread pushThread = new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            if(get_DayOfWeek().startsWith("Mon"))
            showMessage("Hello New Week ");

        }   
    };
    private void showMessage(String data) {
          UiEngine ui = Ui.getUiEngine();
          Screen screen = new Dialog(Dialog.D_OK, data, Dialog.OK,
            Bitmap.getPredefinedBitmap(Bitmap.EXCLAMATION),
            Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
          ui.queueStatus(screen, 1, true);
        }
```

If today is Mon, it will display Dialog. But if today is Sunday, it will not display tomorrow. I want to always check the time but my code only check one time.
I repalce

```
public void run() {
                if(get_DayOfWeek().startsWith("Mon"))
                showMessage("Hello New Week ");

            }
```

by

```
public void run() {
                    while (get_DayOfWeek() != null){
                        if(get_DayOfWeek().startsWith("Sun"))
                            showMessage("Hello New Day ");
                        }

                }
```

but it said "Uncaught Exception, My notifacations is not responding, the process terminated "
Can anyone help me get way to always check the time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite simple.

Implement [RealtimeClockListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/RealtimeClockListener.html) and use it in your application. In your implementation there will be method [clockUpdated()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/RealtimeClockListener.html#clockUpdated%28%29). The BlackBerry Operating System will invoke this method every minute.

Use `System.currentTimeMillis()` in this method to get the current time and use [Calendar](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/java/util/Calendar.html) class to calculate current weekday.

That's it.